# What if I receive a packet without data? (Socket.IO Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, crash, packet

if have the following code:

```
socket.on('getNeighbors', function(data)){
   if( typeof data !== undefined ){
      do something...
   }
});
```

But when I try to send this packet without data my server crashes with the TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined (in this case data).
I understand the reason behind the error, but how can I prevent my server from crashing? How can I catch the error before I get inside of the if-clause? I thought I can manage this by checking if data is undefined, but that is not working :|

Greetings

Comment: typeof returns a string, you need to check against `"undefined"` not `undefined` to avoid the if statement resolving true.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Thank you very much :)